# How do I return a variable from a callback function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to return the value of `tempVar` but I can't figure out how to do this since it is the result of a callback. What is the correct way to handle something like this? I'm not really sure how to word this problem. I was hoping it would work by doing something like `var tempReturned = readPWFile('filename.txt');`  but that doesn't for obvious reasons even if I were to have a 'return' somewhere in the callback. My main goal is to return the results of a `txt` file to a variable. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
function readPWFile(fileName) {
    var tempVar;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, null, gotReadFileEntry, fail);
    });

    function gotReadFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(file) {
        readDataUrl(file);
    }

    function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
            tempVar = evt.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
}
```

Comment: callback implies multiple threads. if that's true, the answer's simple: you can't.

Comment: Do you know of a proper way to read text from a file and assign the results to a variable? Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can't read tempVar beacause it exists only in the readPWFile function.

Comment: @BradChristie Christie: Callbacks don't imply multiple threads. Node.js uses multiple callbacks, yet only one thread.

Comment: Thanks, Donovan.  Is there a better way to do this then? I need to have the results of the file saved to a variable.

Comment: @shmuli: _technically_ JS is single-threaded. I'm not going to argue semantics, but a callback, to me, means I'm awaiting a request to be fulfilled; and either way you look at it you're not going to get the value back in the same function from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide a callback through your API which will grant access to the variable by passing it as a callback argument.

Another alternative to use is through the use of promises, which allow you to work on an object which may not have a result yet.

For instance your function declaration should be

```
function readPWFile(fileName, callback) {
```

And would be invoked with

```
readPWFile(filename, function(tempVar) {
     alert("Successfully received tempVar");
});
```

In essence your code will simply bind this callback function to the reader, rather than using your code. Unless you want to mutate the result in someway of course :

```
function readPWFile(fileName, callback) {
    ...

    function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        // Preference the user's passed in callback function over the previous implementation
        reader.onloadend = callback;
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good start is to read up on Node.js. One of Node's objectives is to provide an non-blocking I/O solution, by using callback patterns. So there's a ton of material on callback patterns in the Node.js community.

Comment: Thanks shmuli, I actually have started studying Node.js. However I need a solution to this problem quickly and I don't yet have the understanding of Node.js to implement something like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an other solution

```
function getContentFile(filePath){

    var FileToOpen = function FileToOpen(filePath)
    {
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) var obj = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Firefox, Opera,...

        else if(window.ActiveXObject) var obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); //Internet Explorer 

        else return(false);


        if (obj.overrideMimeType) obj.overrideMimeType("text/html"); //Avoids bug with Safari


        obj.open("GET", filePath, false);
        obj.send(null);

        if(obj.readyState == 4) return(obj.responseText);
        else return(false);
    }

    var content = FileToOpen(filePath); 
    return content;
}
```

I use this function and I read an html file.

and call this function like this

```
var contentFile = getContentFile(yourFilePath/file.html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a callback to be called when the value updates:

```
function readPWFile(fileName, cb) {
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, null, gotReadFileEntry, fail);
  });
  function gotReadFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
  }
  function gotFile(file) {
    readDataUrl(file);
  }
  function readAsText(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
      cb(evt.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
readPWFile("test", function(val) {
  console.debug("Value: " + val);
});
```